# customise autocompletetextview drop-down background

Tags: android, customization, autocompletetextview

how to customise `autocompletetextview` drop-down background like this image

[image: this image]

currently i'm using `recyclerView`and custom adapter with filterable but i need to visible and hide recyclerview and it manage to hard that's why i finding solution for customise `autocompletetextview` dropdown background , any help can appreciative,Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the relevant code that I used.

**Custom Typeface**

The trick to this one is that I had to set my font to both mAutoCompleteTextView and tvAutocompleteListItem in my Activity.

**Remove Shadow**

I set the background of mAutoCompleteTextView to be R.drawable.autocomplete_dropdown. In that drawable the important line is

```
<stroke
    android:width="0dip"
    android:color="@color/cp_green" />
```

**Radius**

The radius was set in R.drawable.autocomplete_dropdown like this:

```
<corners
    android:radius="20dip"/>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
private void setAutoCompleteListener() {
    mAutoCompleteTextView.setDropDownBackgroundDrawable(
            mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.autocomplete_dropdown));


    mAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(
            new AutoCompleteAdapter(mContext, R.layout.autocomplete_list_item, mLatLng));

    mAutoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String autoCompleteText = (String) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i);
            mAutoCompleteTextView.setText(autoCompleteText);
            initiateSearch();
            hideKeyboard();
        }
    });

    mAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.length() > 0) {
                mClearTextIcon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                mClearTextIcon.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void applyFonts() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Applying Fonts.");

    FontHelper.applyFont(findViewById(R.id.rlMap), mContext);
    font = Font.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

    mAutoCompleteTextView.setTypeface(font.mAvenirLTStandardLight);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_list_item, null);

    TextView tvAutocompleteListItem = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvAutocompleteListItem);
    tvAutocompleteListItem.setTypeface(font.mAvenirLTStandardLight);
}
```

**autocomplete_dropdown.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid
        android:color="@color/white" />

    <stroke
        android:width="0dip"
        android:color="@color/cp_green" />

    <corners
        android:radius="20dip"/>

    <padding
        android:left="25dip"
        android:top="10dip"
        android:right="25dip"
        android:bottom="10dip" />
</shape>
```

**autocomplete_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="25dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/tvAutocompleteListItem"/>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/search"
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:paddingEnd="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar">
    
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/logo_image"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/ibLogoImage"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo"/>
    
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/search_icon"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:id="@+id/ibSearch"
        android:contentDescription="@string/search_hint"/>
    
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/ibClearText"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ibSearch"
        android:background="@drawable/clear_text"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/clear" />
    
    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/actvSearch"
        android:hint="@string/search_or_enter_address"
        android:background="@color/transparent_white"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:completionThreshold="3"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/ibLogoImage"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/ibClearText"
        android:dropDownAnchor="@id/search_bar"
        android:dropDownVerticalOffset="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to Change  the background of dropdown 
setDropDownBackgroundResource();